# Servlet mapping URL is not calling in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I have spring project with web.xml configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my servlet-context.xml

```
resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<default-servlet-handler/> 

<context:component-scan base-package="pk.training.basitMahmood.web.controller" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
</beans:bean>
```

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model uiModel) {

        logger.info("Listing contacts");
        List<Contact> contacts = contactService.findAll();
        uiModel.addAttribute("contacts", contacts);
        logger.info("No. of contacts: " + contacts.size());

        return "contacts/list";

    }

} //end of class ContactController
```

Now when i select run on server then i get the following page

[image]

But when i change the url to `http://localhost:9090/ch17_i18nSupport/contacts` then i get the error that

[image]

I have list.jspx in my contacts folder. Why i am getting not found error?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you add in your servlet-context.xml the bean `<bean name="/contacts" class="pk.training.(...).ContactController"></bean>`?

Comment: I am getting errors in my ContactController class. I have import statements `import pk.training.basitMahmood.domain.Contact;
import pk.training.basitMahmood.service.ContactService;` but code says unresolve imports, don't know why ...

Comment: That happens only if you add that to servlet-context.xml or always? check your project preferences.

Comment: I am getting the error when i type url `http://localhost:9090/WebApplicationWithSpring/contacts` that `No adapter for handler [pk.training.basitMahmood.web.controller.ContactController@893a4a]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler`. Why i am getting this ?

Comment: done. I was missing `<annotation-driven />` tag in my `servlet-context.xml`. Now everything is working fine :)

Comment: `No adapter for handler` indicates that the `@RequestMapping` methods in your controller aren't being picked up. Do you have a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag in your servlet-context.xml?

Comment: Sorry - missed your last update

Comment: One of you could add this an answer and mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this was solved by Basit in the comments, I've also added it as an answer:

No adapter for handler indicates that the `@RequestMapping` methods in your controller aren't being picked up. Do you have a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag in your `servlet-context.xml`?